# How to remove NO_ZERO_DATE from sql_mode in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove `NO_ZERO_DATE` globally from `sql_mode`.

Is it possible to retain any default values while removing it?

Something like pseudocode:
`my.cnf`:

```
sql_mode = $sql_mode(regex.replace(NO_ZERO_DATE, '');
```

Advantage would be that I would not override the defaults of defaults chance in future versions of `mysql`.

Answer (score 8):

```
SET @@sql_mode := REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8fc5c625b1702b64bce4d5865000aee7)

If you need you may store session mode in a variable and revert after your query:

```
SET @@sql_mode := REPLACE(@old_sql_mode := @@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
-- execute your queries
SET @@sql_mode := @old_sql_mode;
```

Comment: Nice, but how can I use this globally in `my.cnf`, not having to execute any scripts on startup of the mysql service?

Comment: @membersound o_O simply edit your options file as a common text file, edit (or add if not exists) `sql-mode="modes"` in its `[mysqld]` section. Or edit service/daemon starting command line and add `--sql-mode="modes"` into it.

Comment: Well but I cannot simply add the `SET @@sql_mode` into `my.cnf` replacing the mode on the fly. But that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @membersound You may make permanent change by editing config file or command line. You may make temporary changes (both global and session) by a query. But you cannot make permanent changes by a query - query cannot edit config file or command line, it is absolutely impossible, no way.

Comment: this will not work in all case i guess

Comment: @vish Demonstrate or at least describe the situation when this won't work please..